# DRYing this Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

Recently, I've started using Rubocop and have been trying to think better about my code and if I can be written better. I have a create and update method that are VERY similar. Rubocop is complaining that the method has too many lines of code [12/10]. I am wondering how you would go about following the DRY principle here. It seems to me that respond_to should be brought to its own private method. But I can't figure out what would be the best way to do that since:

1. The flash can be a :success or :danger
2. One checks if the models saved and the other if it updated.
3. Different rendering depending on if the model saved or if it had an error

I also don't know if I should just be leaving it alone. The fact that it is so redundant is really getting to me though. Ultimate I want to have the cleanest code, I am just not sure if I should DRY this method

```
  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        flash[:success] = 'Category Successfully Created'
        format.html { redirect_to admin_category_path(@category) }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        flash[:danger] = 'Errors in creating category, see below'
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        flash[:success] = 'Category Successfully updated!'
        format.html { redirect_to admin_category_path(@category) }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        flash[:danger] = 'Errors in updating category, missing information'
        format.html { redirect_to action: 'edit', id: @category.id }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Great question! Still, voting to close as "primarily opinion-based" because there is more than one correct answer.

Comment: As this is working code, it is not suitable for SO. You should post it on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to try to make a single method from `create` and `update`, as they serve two very different purposes.

Instead, you could consider the following things:

- do you really need the json format? If you are not using it, you can safely remove those lines;
- remove `@category = Category.find(params[:id])` from `update` and move it to a method in `before_action`

  ```
  before_action :find_category, only: [:edit, :update]

  def find_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end
  ```
- last but not least, Rubocop doesn't always have the right answer: focus on clearness!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was my big issue, I ultimately wanted to have clearness. I will work on some of your suggestions though and see how that goes!

Answer (score 0):

All of the success handling is the same except for a single word in a message; and the JSON handling on error is identical.  So those parts could be extracted into methods called by both create and update.  Not only would the code be more concise, it would be obvious to the reader which behavior was identical and which behavior differed.  I haven't run or tested this code, but here it is:

```
def handle_success(created_or_updated)
  verb = created_or_updated == :created ? 'Created' : 'Updated'
  flash[:success] = "Category Successfully #{verb}"
  format.html { redirect_to admin_category_path(@category) }
  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
end


def handle_failure_json
  format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end


def create
  @category = Category.new(category_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @category.save
      handle_success(:created)
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Errors in creating category, see below'
      format.html { render :new }
      handle_failure_json
    end
  end
end


def update
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @category.update(category_params)
      handle_success(:updated)
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Errors in updating category, missing information'
      format.html { redirect_to action: 'edit', id: @category.id }
      handle_failure_json
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, this is best pactice

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html